# Escaping reserverved characters in SOSL queries

Tags: sosl, dynamic-sosl

Escaping reserverved characters with backslash as described in Force documentation (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm) give unexpected results:

1. Using syntax with quotes (FIND '*company\\?*' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ...) I am getting errors like "Invalid string literal '*company\?*'. Illegal character sequence '\?' in string literal."
2. Using syntax with braces (FIND {*company\\?*} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ...) I am getting empty result, which is actually wrong result

*Updated*. Tried 4 backslashes, result - empty list:

```
String soslQuery = 'FIND \'worldwide company\\\\?\' IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING Account(ID, NAME)';
List<List<SObject>> searchList = Search.query(soslQuery);
for(Account account : (List<Account>)searchList[0])
{
    System.debug(account.name);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using single quotes around your search term, I assume you are running this in apex inside of square brackets, like so:

```
list<list<sobject>> results = [find '*company\\?' in all fields returning contact (id, name)];
```

I also assume you are trying to search for a literal "?" in your result.  It isn't intuitive, but it appears that Apex processes the string once, and then the SOSL engine processes it again.  So you'll need to re-double your backslashes, like so:

```
list<list<string>> results = [find '*company\\\\?' in all fields returning contact (id, name)];
```

If you look at the apex log for my version, you'll see this:

```
SOSL_EXECUTE_BEGIN [1]|FIND '*company\\?' IN all FIELDS RETURNING contact(id,name)
```

Here it has changed each pair of backslashes into single backslash; I believe they are being converted to a single backslash by the SOSL engine.

Comment: Yes I am searching for Account witn Name 'worldwide company?'.

Comment: The four backslashes should give you the result you want.

Comment: I am having issues with basically all of SOSL reserved characters. I've tried 4 backslashes but query returned empty list. Have you got valid results during execution of your query?

Comment: Yes, I have, executing from apex as above.  How are you attempting to run the sosl query?  If apex code, can you add your code to your question?

Comment: Could you please explain me how you assigned List<List<SObject>> variable which is returned by SOSL query to variable List<List<String>> result? Did it execute successfully?

Comment: Sorry, transcription error :)  You are correct, it was list<list<SObject>>.

Comment: Do you have any ideas why I am getting empty list when using 4 backslashes to escape reserved characters?