# Sanitize a string before injecting it into SOSL

Tags: soap-api, sosl, string, .net

Is there a way through the .net framework or some other package to sanitize strings so that they can be safely used in sosl? Is there any larger standard that SOSL falls under?

I was able to find [How to pass a variable to the SOQL where clause?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/28412/3357) and [Escaping reserverved characters in SOSL queries](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/25770/3357), but they both deal with solving specific cases rather than a general solution.

I would prefer not to roll my own solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Dynamic SOSL - SOSL Injection](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_sosl.htm#apex_sosl_injection):

> SOSL injection is a technique by which a user causes your application to execute database methods you did not intend by passing SOSL statements into your code. This can occur in Apex code whenever your application relies on end user input to construct a dynamic SOSL statement and you do not handle the input properly.
>
> To prevent SOSL injection, use the `escapeSingleQuotes` method. This method adds the escape character (\) to all single quotation marks in a string that is passed in from a user. The method ensures that all single quotation marks are treated as enclosing strings, instead of database commands.

Based on that is should be sufficient to escape any single quote characters in the user based input before merging it with your dynamic SOSL.

Comment: Is the escapeSingleQuotes method only available in the apex language?

Comment: That particular method is apex specific. In C# you would do something like `s = s.Replace("'", @"\'");`

Comment: Yeah, that is what I'm doing now, but I would like to have it be more inclusive as [technically the special characters go beyond '](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_quotedstringescapes.htm), without writing my own library.

Comment: I don't know of a library that includes such a function for  C#. You might find something in the [Salesforce Toolkits for .NET](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/01/announcing-the-salesforce-toolkits-for-net.html). Now I want to send the [Bell character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) in to see I can make noises on the Salesforce servers.

Comment: I know, I couldn't believe the bell was in there, along with form feed.